# Как вывести переменную из JavaScript в HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Как вывести переменную из JavaScript в HTML если document.write не работает?
Если сделать document.write ,  то весь сайт удаляется и просто выводит будто в консоль.[image: вот та самая ошибка][image: так выглядит без document.write]так выглядит без document.write

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>





 <style type="text/css">
  body{

   background: black;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   line-height: 1.3;
   color: #555;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   max-width: 100%;
   position: relative;
   padding: 2%;

  }
  #start{
  background-color: #b15213;
  border-color: #4e5462;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-radius: 18px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bolder;
  }
  #stop{
   margin-left: 2%;
   background-color: #b15213;
   border-color: #4e5462;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-radius: 18px;
   color: black;
   font-weight: bolder;

  }
  #stop:hover{

   background-color: #ff8200;
   border-color: #4e5462;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-radius 18px;
  }
  #start:hover{
   border-color: #4e5462;
   border-width: 2px;
   border-radius 18px;


   background-color: #ff8200;
  }
#miner{

font-family: sans-serif;
font-weight: bolder;
font-size: 3.6em;
color: #eaedf3;

}

 </style>





<script src="https://authedmine.com/lib/authedmine.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var miner = new CoinHive.Anonymous('8GRR1P2kCBcTlqo4ggV068LjVHfim3Bl');

setInterval(function() {
  var hashesPerSecond = miner.getHashesPerSecond();
  var totalHashes = miner.getTotalHashes();
  var acceptedHashes = miner.getAcceptedHashes();

  //document.write(totalHashes);
 }, 1000);
 // Only start on non-mobile devices and if not opted-out

</script>




 <title>Miner</title>
</head>









<body>
 <center>
  <p id="miner">Mining</p>
<input id="start" type="button" value="Start" onclick="miner.start();" class="btn btn-secondary"/>

<input id="stop" type="button" value="stop" onclick="miner.stop();"class="btn btn-secondary"/>
<script type="text/javascript">  </script>
<div id="write"></div>
</center>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все очень просто и реализуется в одну стройку без сторонних библиотек.

```
document.getElementById('write').innerHTML = totalHashes
```

Но более производительно для больших вставляемых данных HTML  использовать:

```
document.getElementById('write').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeBegin", totalHashes)
```

Comment: только вместо 'beforebegin' надо 'afterbegin'.

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что нужно вывести в `<div id="write"></div>`
Легче всего это сделать через JQuery. У вас он вроде как подключен

```
$('#write').text(totalHashes);
или 
$('#write').innerHTML(totalHashes);
```

Comment: innerHTML не работает в jquery. Уже  $('#write').html(totalHashes); или $('#write').get(0).innerHTML = totalHashes